# Discord bot issues - nothing happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am making a Discord bot for moderator applications for a server, and I followed a tutorial. The only issue is that when I run the command, nothing happens.

Code:

**Apply.js**

```js
const { Message } = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('../client/Client');
module.exports = {
  name: 'apply',
  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {String[]} args
   */
  run: async(client, message, args) => {
    const questions = [`What is your age?`, `What is your minecraft username?`, `Do you have a working mic?`, `What would you like to specialize in?`, `What experience do you have with previous discord/minecraft servers?`, `Why should we choose you?`, `Tell us about yourself!! What are your likes and dislikes, what do you find enjoyable, etc!`];
    const dmChannel = await message.author.send('Welcome to your application!');
    const collector = dmChannel.channel.createMessageCollector((msg) => msg.author.id == message.author.id);
    let i = 0;
    const res = [];
    dmChannel.channel.send(questions[0]);
    collector.on('collect', async(messag) => {
      if(questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
      const answer = msg.content;
      res.push({ question: questions[i], answer });
      i++;
      if(questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
      else {
        dmChannel.channel.send(questions[i]);
      }
    });
    collector.on('end', async(collected, reason) => {
        if(reason == 'MAX') {
            const data = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name.toLowerCase() == 'applications' && ch.type == 'text');
            await data.send(`${message.member || message.author} (${message.author.tag}) submitted an application!\n${res.map(d => `${d.question} - ${d.answer}`).join("\n")}`)
        }
    })
  }
}
```

**Client.js**

```js
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { join } = require('path')
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
class ApplicationClient extends Client {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.commands = new Collection();
    };
    start(token, cmd) {
        this.prefix = 'a!'
        this.login(token);
        readdirSync(join(process.cwd(), cmd)).map((data) => {
            const file = require(join(process.cwd(), cmd, data));
            this.commands.set(file, file);
        });
        this.on('ready', () => console.log(``));
        this.on('message', async(message) => {
            if(message.author.bot ||!message.guild ||!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.prefix)) return;
            const [ cmd, ...args] = message.content.slice(this.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
            const command = this.commands.get(cmd.toLowerCase());
            if(!command) return;
            command.run(this, message, args).catch(console.error);
        });
    }
};
module.exports = ApplicationClient;
```

I've been trying this for 6 hours and have no clue what went wrong. In Node.js, everything works fine, the program runs. But if I type `a!apply` in Discord, nothing happens. Nothing shows up on the node.js console either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call the ApplicationClient.start() method

Comment: index.js is where i have it. Its ```new ApplicationClient().start('token', './commands')```
(token is a bunch of numbers, not  "token")

Comment: Can you debug your `Client.js` and check, if your `command var` is undefined / empty?